# Spring 3.5. When user login then logout and try to login once again he get an error about user\pass

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have spring(4.0.6) web application. I've noticed that when user logon then logout and try to logon once again gets an error about user\pass.
I don't have web.xml file because I am using `SpringBootServletInitializer` class to config my application. 
I've add to my configuration such bean

```
    @Bean
    public ServletListenerRegistrationBean<HttpSessionEventPublisher> httpSessionEventPublisher()
    {
    return new ServletListenerRegistrationBean<HttpSessionEventPublisher>(new HttpSessionEventPublisher());
    }
```

and in security config I have this:

```
 http.sessionManagement()
.maximumSessions(1).expiredUrl("/login?expired")
.maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true)
.and()
.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
.invalidSessionUrl("/");
```

As I understand previous session is alive and because of Maximum session = 1 user can't login once again. What should I do to avoid it?

Comment: May you explain little bit better? In the first half of the post you talk about errors on username/password; then you need to kill the session and IMHO I don't see any connection between the 2 things

Comment: And there is no Spring 3.5!

Comment: Ooops, sorry, my mistake, correct

Comment: Authentication request failed: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionAuthenticationException: Maximum sessions of 1 for this principal exceeded

Comment: .maximumSessions(1) means one user can login or its 1minute time interval?

Answer (score 0):

You should `invalidate the user session` when he logout. Below is the piece of code. Need to pass the userid.

`UserInfo` is the `POJO`

```
public boolean invalidateUserSession(Long userId) {

    List<Object> principalsList = sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals();
    Object targetPrincipal = null;
    for (Object principal : principalsList) {
        if (principal instanceof UserInfo) {
            if (((UserInfo) principal).getId().equals(userId)) {
                targetPrincipal = principal;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (targetPrincipal == null) {
        return false;
    }

    List<SessionInformation> userSessionsList = sessionRegistry.getAllSessions(targetPrincipal, false);

    for (SessionInformation x : userSessionsList) {
        x.expireNow();
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Can you give more info. Where I should place this code?

Comment: @Alexandr Say you have a `Logout` button on `JSP` page, map with your controller and call the method there.

Comment: But what if user close browser without clicking the button or session expired?

Comment: @Alexandr closing browser or keeping page idle, it is something which we cannot control, you should have some configurable timeout, wherein you can have one pre filter which runs before every request, and checks for token validity.

You can go thru tutorials for the same, lot of stuff will be available, also do except answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: Can I do this way. Config time out and config url when session is expired to /logout and write this controller
`@Controller
@RequestMapping("/logout")
public class LogoutController
{

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String logout(HttpSession session, SessionRegistryImpl sessionRegistry)
    { 
  your code
 }` 
}

Comment: Strange but sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals() is empty.

Comment: @Alexandr Need to register `sessionRegistry` also.